# Split String Azure Function to Insert Data to Azure Table Storage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage

i try to insert data from IOT Hub by using Azure Function to insert the data to Azure Table storage with this

```
    'use strict';

    // This function is triggered each time a message is received in the IoT hub.
    // The message payload is persisted in an Azure storage table

    module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {
    context.log('Message received: ' + JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage));
    var date = Date.now();
    var partitionKey = Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '';
    var rowKey = date + '';
    context.bindings.outputTable = {
     "partitionKey": partitionKey,
     "rowKey": rowKey,
     "message":  JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage)
    };
    context.done();
    };
```

It did works, but the data is only in one string like this

```
    [{"gwName":"Gateway-001","wellName":"AI-07","wellId":"BTG-80","pressure":39.02,"flow":0,"temperature":146.55,"rtc":1,"sdcard":1,"timestamp":1516562384}]
```

I want to seperate each data by it's column, so i try this

```
    module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {
       context.log('Message received: ' + JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage));
       var date = Date.now();
       var deviceData = Object.assign({ "partitionKey": Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '', "rowKey": date + '' + process.hrtime()[1] + '' }, iotHubMessage)  
       context.bindings.outputTable = deviceData;
       context.log(deviceData);
       context.done();
    };
```

the data will come like this

```
{ '0': 
   { gwName: 'Gateway-001',
     wellName: 'AI-10-81',
     wellId: 'BTG-110',
     pressure: 37.58,
     flow: 2.03,
     temperature: 110.96,
     rtc: 1,
     sdcard: 1,
     timestamp: 1517328108 },
  partitionKey: '17561',
  rowKey: '1517302524398738092399' }
```

Yes, the data has been seperated but there is an error warning like this

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.storageiottrigger. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned:. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code.
```

I think there is related with this part `{ '0':` i don't know where that part came from. Need some help here, thanks.

Comment: Can you try changing this line of code: `var deviceData = Object.assign({ "partitionKey": Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '', "rowKey": date + '' + process.hrtime()[1] + '' }, iotHubMessage)` to `var deviceData = Object.assign({ "partitionKey": Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '', "rowKey": date + '' + process.hrtime()[1] + '' }, iotHubMessage[0])`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Wow, it's working thank you very much